# Configuring Jetty to accept connections from all hosts on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, jetty

I want Jetty to serve connections from any host on port 8080. My `/etc/default/jetty` file has: -

```
NO_START=0
JETTY_HOST=
JETTY_PORT=8080
```

The server is an EC2 small instance based on a Lucid Lynx 32 bit server AMI. APT is configured with multiverse enabled, and the canonical partner repository enabled. Jetty is 6.1.22 from from the partner repository.

When I start jetty using `sudo /etc/init.d jetty start`, it works, and listens to connections from localhost,  but not to any others: -

```
ubuntu@ip-10-224-70-51:/etc/network/if-pre-up.d$ sudo netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
413/sshd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN
5655/jsvc
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
413/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
260/dhclient3
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    P
ath
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1407     1/init              @
/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4021     407/dbus-daemon     /
var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Any ideas on why my Jetty config doesn't seem to be listening to other hosts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it!  You need: -

```
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

to listen to other hosts. So a minimal /etc/default/jetty file includes: -

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
NO_START=0
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
JETTY_PORT=8080
```

Comment: some jetty distributions don't pass JETTY_HOST env var. add `-Djetty.port=$JETTY_PORT` to the JAVA_OPTIONS env (or similar)

Comment: For some odd reason on Ubuntu this option is labelled as being which hosts jetty will accept connections from. Had me fooled for a while.

Comment: You can also use `JETTY_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jetty` (with double quotes): `JETTY_ARGS="jetty.host=127.0.0.1 jetty.port=8080 jetty.spdy.port=8443 jetty.secure.port=443"`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that want's to use Jetty on Ubuntu with Sun's Java JDK, these are the things that need to be changed `/etc/default/jetty` file:

```
NO_START=0    # so jetty can be started.

JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0    # so jetty listens to all hosts.

JETTY_PORT=8999    # optionally, port on which jetty listens (in my case 8999).

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun    # very important, your JAVA_HOME dir.
```

That's all what is needed to run jetty on ubuntu.
*(I spent an hour and realised I was missing `JAVA_HOME` though I do have it defined in `.bashrc`)*